# Adding icon to ion-option -Ionic-

Tags: ionic3

Can I add icon to ion-option ionic in the ion-select component

something like this :

```
<ion-select interface="popover" >
     <ion-option *ngFor="let view of views; ">  
           <ion-icon name="add"></ion-icon>
           {{view.name}}     
     </ion-option>
</ion-select>
```